# Dockerized Spring Cloud Gateway request header too large

Tags: docker, docker-compose, microservices, netty, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to solve problem with my app. When I start my app locally on desktop, everything is all right. When I start it inside docker and send post or get request I got respond from Postman 431Request Header Fields Too Large.
Can anyone please help me?
HTTP GET request to this url GET http://localhost:8181/api/product
Here is my docker compose file

```
---
version: '3.7'
services:
  ## MySQL Docker Compose Config
  postgres-order:
    container_name: postgres-order
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: order-service
      POSTGRES_USER: ptechie
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-order:/data/postgres
    expose:
      - "5431"
    ports:
      - "5431:5431"
    command: -p 5431
    restart: always

  postgres-inventory:
    container_name: postgres-inventory
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: inventory-service
      POSTGRES_USER: ptechie
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-inventory:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always

  ## Mongo Docker Compose Config
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:4.4.14-rc0-focal
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    expose:
      - "27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-data:/data/db


  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.1
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.1
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://broker:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

#  ## Zipkin
#  zipkin:
#    image: openzipkin/zipkin
#    container_name: zipkin
#    ports:
#      - "9411:9411"
#
  ## Eureka Server
  discovery-server:
    image: danicazdravkovic/discovery-server:latest
    container_name: discovery-server
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
#    depends_on:
#      - zipkin

  api-gateway:
    image: danicazdravkovic/api-gateway:latest
    container_name: api-gateway
    ports:
      - "8181:8080"
    expose:
      - "8181"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
#      - LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK_SECURITY= TRACE
    depends_on:
#      - zipkin
      - discovery-server


  ## Product-Service Docker Compose Config
  product-service:
    container_name: product-service
    image: danicazdravkovic/product-service:latest
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway

  ## Order-Service Docker Compose Config
  order-service:
    container_name: order-service
    image: danicazdravkovic/order-service:latest
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-order:5431/order-service
    depends_on:
      - postgres-order
      - broker
#      - zipkin
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway

  ## Inventory-Service Docker Compose Config
  inventory-service:
    container_name: inventory-service
    image: danicazdravkovic/inventory-service:latest
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-inventory:5432/inventory-service
    depends_on:
      - postgres-inventory
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway

  ## Notification-Service Docker Compose Config
  notification-service:
    container_name: notification-service
    image: danicazdravkovic/notification-service:latest
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
#      - zipkin
      - broker
      - discovery-server
      - api-gateway
```

And here is log

```
2023-08-28 14:47:10 2023-08-28T12:47:10.695Z DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] .f.h.o.ObservedResponseHttpHeadersFilter : Will instrument the response
2023-08-28 14:47:10 2023-08-28T12:47:10.696Z DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] .f.h.o.ObservedResponseHttpHeadersFilter : The response was handled for observation {name=http.client.requests(null), error=null, context=name='http.client.requests', contextualName='null', error='null', lowCardinalityKeyValues=[http.method='GET', http.status_code='UNKNOWN', spring.cloud.gateway.route.id='product-service', spring.cloud.gateway.route.uri='lb://product-service'], highCardinalityKeyValues=[http.uri='http://localhost:8181/api/product'], map=[class io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer$Sample='io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer$Sample@745b2658', class io.micrometer.core.instrument.LongTaskTimer$Sample='SampleImpl{duration(seconds)=1.090919261, duration(nanos)=1.090919261E9, startTimeNanos=7682403671438}'], parentObservation={name=http.server.requests(null), error=null, context=name='http.server.requests', contextualName='null', error='null', lowCardinalityKeyValues=[exception='none', method='GET', outcome='SUCCESS', status='200', uri='UNKNOWN'], highCardinalityKeyValues=[http.url='/api/product'], map=[class io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer$Sample='io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer$Sample@159ad82d', class io.micrometer.core.instrument.LongTaskTimer$Sample='SampleImpl{duration(seconds)=1.097201581, duration(nanos)=1.097201581E9, startTimeNanos=7682397843526}'], parentObservation=null}}
2023-08-28 14:47:10 2023-08-28T12:47:10.697Z TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] o.s.c.g.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter  : NettyWriteResponseFilter start inbound: 2f267dd5, outbound: [690e1732-641] 
2023-08-28 14:47:10 2023-08-28T12:47:10.699Z TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] o.s.c.g.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter      : spring.cloud.gateway.requests tags: [tag(httpMethod=GET),tag(httpStatusCode=431),tag(outcome=CLIENT_ERROR),tag(routeId=product-service),tag(routeUri=lb://product-service),tag(status=REQUEST_HEADER_FIELDS_TOO_LARGE)]
```

I was reading about changing header size but I dont know how to do it inside docker compose file and Docker containers

Comment: Docker doesn't do anything to the networking, the issue is with Netty/Spring. How big are the headers you are sending? When you find how large are the headers, you can increase `server.max-http-header-size` to accommodate it.

Comment: I used WireShark to see header of requests. 
When I start my app in Intellij: header size is 20 bytes and total length is 41
When I start my app in docker containers: header size is 20 bytes and total length is 81
I put server.max-http-header-size=100KB in my properties file in api and product service, but it still doesn't work. @Augusto